# Polymer component google-signin not firing events?

Tags: javascript, polymer, google-authentication

I have created a new starter-kit project using polymer-cli 1.7 and I am trying to add Google authentication using the `google-signin` element.

The sign in button is displayed and I am able to use it to sign in, but the `signedIn` property is not being set and the events (e.g. `is-authorized-changed`) are not firing.

`is-authorized-changed` fires twice when the page is first loaded but does not fire again when I sign in or out.

```
...
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/google-signin/google-signin.html">
...
<dom-module id="cx-dashboard">
  <template>
    <style>
      ...
    </style>

    <app-location route="{{route}}"></app-location>
    <app-route route="{{route}}" pattern="/:page" data="{{routeData}}" tail="{{subroute}}"></app-route>
    <app-drawer-layout fullbleed force-narrow="true">
      <!-- Drawer content -->
      <app-drawer>
        <app-toolbar>Menu</app-toolbar>
        <iron-selector selected="[[page]]" attr-for-selected="name" class="drawer-list" role="navigation">

          <a name="view1" href="/view1">View1</a>
          <a name="view2" href="/view2">View2</a>
        </iron-selector>
      </app-drawer>
      <!-- Main content -->
      <app-header-layout has-scrolling-region>
        <app-header condenses reveals effects="waterfall">
          <app-toolbar>
            <paper-icon-button icon="menu" drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
            <div main-title>Dashboard</div>
            {{signedIn}}
            <google-signin client-id="my-client-id" hosted-domain="mydomain"
            signed-in="{{signedIn}}"></google-signin>
          </app-toolbar>
        </app-header>
        <iron-pages selected="[[page]]" attr-for-selected="name" fallback-selection="view404" role="main">
          <my-view1 name="view1"></my-view1>
          <my-view2 name="view2"></my-view2>
          <my-view3 name="view3"></my-view3>
          <my-view404 name="view404"></my-view404>
        </iron-pages>
      </app-header-layout>
    </app-drawer-layout>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'cx-dashboard',

      properties: {
        page: {
          type: String,
          reflectToAttribute: true,
          observer: '_pageChanged'
        }
      },
      listeners: {
        'is-authorized-changed': '_handleAuthChange',
        'google-signin-success': '_signInSuccess',
        'google-signed-out': '_signedOut',
        'google-signin-aware-success': '_signInSuccess'
      },
      observers: [
        '_routePageChanged(routeData.page)'
      ],

      _routePageChanged: function(page) {
        this.page = page || 'view1';
      },

      _pageChanged: function(page) {
        // Load page import on demand. Show 404 page if fails
        var resolvedPageUrl = this.resolveUrl('my-' + page + '.html');
        this.importHref(resolvedPageUrl, null, this._showPage404, true);
      },

      _showPage404: function() {
        this.page = 'view404';
      },
      _signInNecessary: function() {
        console.log('_signInNecessary')
      },
      _signInSuccess: function() {
        console.log('_signInSuccess')
      },
      _signedOut: function() {
        console.log('_signedOut')
      },
      _handleAuthChange: function(event) {
        console.log('_handleAuthChange', event)
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem (I see the is-authorized-change event on every change): http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/qawaxw?editors=1010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had not configured the correct port in the [Google console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials).

Thanks to @tony19 for the working example.